-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "about:srcdoc" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)" - ios release build
I have an issue with iframe on production build iOS. Locally works fine but in release build i just get white screen. Foun error message in debugger:
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "about:srcdoc" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
Added originWhitelist={['*', "about:srcdoc"]} to WebView.
allowed about scheme in info.plist. Tried adding exception domains. Nothing works.
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>about</string>
</array>

